# Any easy way to extract details from a HTM webpage?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the following address from the 10-Q on this webpage and need help getting it to work: https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000095017022012936/tsla-20220630.htm

1 Tesla Road
Austin, Texas

```
URL = f'https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/{cik}/{accessionNumber}/{primaryDocument}'
response = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
soup.find_all('dei:EntityAddressAddressLine1')
```

Where:

- cik = 0001318605
- accessionNumber = 000095017022012936
- primaryDocument
  = tsla-20220630.htm

Comment: It looks like that page is relying heavily on JavaScript to load the page contents, so you're going have to use a webdriver and a tool like Selenium to actually load the pages you want in a browser in order to generate the content.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortently, because I am running this on DataBricks, using Selenium isn't an immediate solution I can take. However, it does look like this method works!

```
r = requests.get(f'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/{cik}/{accessionNumber.replace("-", "")}/{accessionNumber}.txt', headers=headers)
raw_10k = r.text
city = raw_10k.split('Entity Address, City or Town</a></td>\n<td class="text">')[1].split('<span></span>')[0]
print(city)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already realized, the data is added from the `https://www.sec.gov/Archives....` site, and you would need something like selenium to get it from the `https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives....` site.

[The URL I used was https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000095017022012936/tsla-20220630.htm and I just copied the cookies and headers from my own browser to pass into the request. I tried to open the link in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74130417/12652373), but I got a `NoSuchKey` error...]

*If* you've managed to fetch a html containing 10-Q form, I feel that the simplest way to extract the address would be with [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```py
[s.text for s in soup.select('td *[name^="dei:EntityAddress"]')]
```

will return `['1 Tesla Road', 'Austin', 'Texas', '78725']` and so, with

```py
print(', '.join([
    s.get_text(strip=True) for s in 
    soup.select('p>span *[name^="dei:EntityAddress"]')
    if 'ZipCode' not in s.get('name') # excludes zipcode
]))
```

`1 Tesla Road, Austin, Texas` will be printed.

You can also use

```py
addrsCell = soup.find(attrs={'name':'dei:EntityAddressAddressLine1'})
if addrsCell and addrsCell.find_parent('td'): # is not None
  print(' '.join([
      s.text for s in addrsCell.find_parent('td').select('p')]))
```

to get `1 Tesla Road Austin, Texas`, which is exactly as you formatted it in your question.